# error problems when doing opentrading

Tags: solidity, metamask, gas, etherscan

after deploy contact and verifying contract i went through adding liquidity and i was ready to launch coin and i click on open trading and receive an error on meta Mask
that says we were not able to estimate gas. there might be an error in the contract and this transaction may fail so i rejected it and tried it again same error so i clicked i want to proceed anyways and i got this error Fail with error 'UniswapV2: PAIR_EXISTS'
i am not sure how this is or what is wrong with the contract
if anyone knows this can you please help
[image]